# Automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserving flag of basis are isomorphic to the group of upper triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

In Fulton and Harris' *Representation Theory*, it is mentioned that

1. The group upper triangular matrices can be considered as the automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserving the flag of spans of basis vectors.
2. Additionally, matrices preserving a different basis are isomorphic to the group of upper triangular matrices.

Here is the precise definition from Fulton and Harris:

> ... the group $B_n$ of *upper-triangular* matrices; equivalently, the subgroup of automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserving the flag
> $$0 = V_0 \subset V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \dots \subset V_{n-1} \subset V_n = \mathbb{R}^n,$$
> where $V_i$ is the span of the standard basis vectors $e_1, \dots, e_i$. Note that choosing a different basis and correspondingly a different flag yields a different subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n\mathbb{R}$, but one isomorphisc to (indeed, conjugate to) $B_n$.

I see the first point: Take $n=3$ as an example, any upper triangular matrix

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & a_3 \\
0 & b_2 & b_3 \\
0 & 0 & c_3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

preserves the flag complex generated by the spans of the basis vectors $v_1 = (1, 0, 0)^T$, $v_2 = (0, 1, 0)^T$, $v_3 = (0, 0, 1)^T$ because $Mv_1 = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$ which spans the same space as $v_1$, $M \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ 0 & b_2 \\ 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$ which spans the same space as $(v_1, v_2)$, and same thing with $M \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{bmatrix}$. Obviously, this can be generalized to any finite $n$.

However, I am having trouble with the second point. While the second point seems intuitively true, how should I approach to proving it? I think that every matrix can be conjugate to an upper triangular matrix, but I am struggling to make a connection between conjugation and the notion of preserving a different flag complex.

Comment: Starting from a flag $V_1 \subset V_2 \dots$, write down a basis $v_i$ such that $v_i \in V_i \setminus V_{i-1}$, then write the set of matrices preserving the flag in this basis.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the hint, I will try to write a solution to my own question below.

Comment: Please do not use pictures of symbols for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched, and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @ronno I appreciate it, thank you